# How to update the textfile that we had written with bufferedwriter in java

Tags: java

I want to make a student data that saved into textfile by bufferedwriter (i've finish this part) but i also want to make update part so i make the other JForm
here is the code :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    String SID = atf.getText();
    String FN = btf.getText();
    String LN = ltf.getText();
    String CN = ctf.getText();
    String EM = etf.getText();
    String CarNum = cartf.getText();
    Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();

    try{
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("asd.txt");
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(file);
        buffer.write("Student ID : " + SID);
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write("First Name : " + FN);
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write("Last Name : " + LN);
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write("Contact Number : " + CN);
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write("Email : " + EM);
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write("Car Number : " + CarNum);
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write("Date Of Registration : " + cal.getTime());
        buffer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data has been saved");
    dispose();
}
```

and after all , i want to make another method with JTextField
here is the code

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String NSID=NSIDx.getText();
    String NFN=NFNx.getText(); 
    String NLN=NLNx.getText(); 
    String NC=NCNx.getText(); 
    String NE=NEx.getText(); 
    String NCarNum=NCarNumx.getText();}
```

i want to input the second code to update the first code that means i must change the value of SID become NSID

i dont know how to use private method in other private method . is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

best you use **xml** file to store the data.
so you can construct a structure for your data and using parsers can easily update,insert, delete also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to call a private method from another private method. The notion of privacy is only for the users of the object and is not applicable for methods in the object itself. By the way, since the code is similar in both these methods, you should separate it out in another private method and call that method from these two event handlers.